# return statement after throw error in matlab

Tags: matlab

For my simple code[image: here] It seems that the return statement is not needed after the error statement.

1. Does that mean the function would be early terminated once error is thrown?
2. If the above is true, what if i do want to process with the rest of function even after an error is thrown. For example, i can still compute c = a - b in my function.

Comment: 1) true. 2) Then don't throw an error, just throw a _warning_, this will not stop code execution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, the error terminates the program.
2. As suggested by [Hoki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460361/hoki), use a `warning` instead.

Note: Your function will throw anyway, if only modifying the code to use `warning`. This is because the return variable `c` is not assigned before after the `if`-statement.